# Where to use table types and where structures?

Tags: abap

Why we use Table Type in SAP/ABAP? We can declare as type of table as shown below.

```
DATA it_doc TYPE TABLE OF table_name.
```

And if I want to store for specific attribute of table, I can use structure type.

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF st_student,
        sid TYPE i,
        sname TYPE c LENGTH 8,
    END OF st_student.
DATA student TYPE st_student.
```

Is there any performance difference between table type and structure?

Comment: A table is more or less like a list of elements. In your example, one structure represents one student. A table could be used to store multiple students.

Comment: I think, I don't get the question. Could you try to elaborate a bit more about your thoughts?

Comment: @lausek if i want internal table exactly as table, we can use to declare as type of table. And if i want internal table with specific column, we can use either Table Type or STRUCTURE type. So my question is, what is use of table type if we have structure. As i understand TT is same as structure. And i thought that structure is faster than TT on performance basis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are talking about table types in the data dictionary. Since you can use the statement `TYPE TABLE OF <structure>` it might seem unintuitive to create a table type on top of that. However you need this table type if you want to pass a whole table as an argument to a Function Module or Class Method.

For example, you cannot write the following:

```
 methods PASS_TABLE
    returning
      value(rt_table) TYPE TABLE OF <structure> .
```

In this case you have to use a dictionary table type:

```
 methods PASS_TABLE
    returning
      value(rt_table) TYPE  dict_table_type .
```

Answer (score 4):

No, tables and structures are actually very different, so your concerns about performance are a bit unnecessary. As I stated in my comment, a table is a list of elements.

### Example

You want to store information about a school class. Your application should be able to store data like name, birthdate, gender etc. of one student. To group those fields together, one would use a structure:

```
TYPES:
    BEGIN OF student,
        name   TYPE string,
        birth  TYPE d,
        gender TYPE char1,
   END OF student.
```

Now you can declare a variable of type `student` and assign data like that:

```
DATA stud1 TYPE student.
stud1-name = 'Joe'.
...
```

You now want to put students together in a classroom. You'll need an internal table for this.

```
TYPES classroom TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF student WITH EMPTY KEY.
" ignore STANDARD and WITH EMPTY KEY for now

DATA e3fi TYPE classroom.

" fill table here
DATA joe TYPE student.
" init joe
APPEND joe TO e3fi.

DATA susan TYPE student.
" init susan
APPEND susan TO e3fi
```

After that your classroom `e3fi` contains two students `susan` and `joe`. Each of these students has individual name, birthdate and so on.